# Como posso limpar o buffer?

Tags: c

Estou a trabalhar com ficheiro. Tenho dificuldades de limpar o buffer já usei o `fflush(stdin)` depois de ler mas não funciona.

```
void EscreverFicheiro(FILE * ptr,LISTA dados){

    ptr = fopen("listagem","wb");
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\t\tPOR FAVOR INSIRA SEUS DADOS\n\n");
    printf("\t\tNOME: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(dados.nome);
    printf("\t\tRUA: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(dados.rua);
    printf("\t\tCIDADE: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(dados.cidade);
    printf("\t\tPROVINCIA: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(dados.provincia);
    printf("\t\tCOD POSTAL: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(dados.codpost);
    fflush(stdin);
    fwrite(&dados,sizeof(struct lista_type),1,ptr);

    fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Usaste a tag CSS e querias usar C, certo? Ou será C++?

Comment: é mesmo em C...

Comment: Usei uma estrutura para pegar informações e guardar no ficheiro...

Answer (score 1):

Alternativas ao `fflush`:

```
fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
```

Ou então:

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

Comment: Obrigado!   mas acabei de descubrir que o erro não é no ficheiro mas sim na estrutura... Eu declarei da seguinte maneira:

Comment: typedef struct lista_type{
 char nome[40];
 char rua[30];
 char cidade[4];
 char provincia[3];
 char codpost[10];
}LISTA;                                                                                                                         Quando vou ler os dados o campo provincia armazena alem dos seus caracteres isto é ele vai buscar ao cod postal

Comment: Acredito que sua dúvida tenha sido respondida. Se tiver outras dúvidas, sinta-se à vontade para criar novas perguntas.